# Long lived http sessions in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, session, tomcat

I'm developing REST end points for an application using spring mvc. These APIs are all authenticated using custom login logic. I have a mobile app which would be calling these APIs and since it is a mobile app, I want to ensure that the session is alive for a very long time (a year maybe). I'm currently using redis backed implementation for session storage with tomcat as container. This is the library I'm currently using for the same: [git](https://github.com/zinin/tomcat-redis-session). Any suggestions around ways of persisting this indefinitely?

Comment: Do you have problems setting session timeout on Tomcat? I can see you have already found a way to persist a session outside of Tomcat. What is the problem now?

Comment: I'm actually facing problems in setting a very high value for maxInactiveInterval. As of now, Ive set it to 1 year (in secs) but it expires within 1800 secs. It looks like it is taking a default value which is hard coded to 1800 here: https://github.com/zinin/tomcat-redis-session/blob/17c18f552e1b42e22f5891d25b2137bd987bc106/src/main/java/ru/zinin/redis/session/RedisManager.java. I wanted to know if there are any standard ways of approaching this problem of persisting sessions indefinitely in general.

Comment: Well, judging by the code you have linked it is possible to override default. Have you tried to add attribute to your configuration (a year in seconds): <Manager className="ru.zinin.redis.session.RedisManager" maxInactiveInterval="31536000"/> ?

Comment: Yes this is what Ive given: <Manager className="ru.zinin.redis.session.RedisManager" host="localhost" maxInactiveInterval="31536000"/> After 1800 secs, when I try doing KEYS * on redis-cli, it gives me 0 results.

Comment: I can see that 'maxInactiveInterval' is also set while 'sessionTimeout' is modified. Try to set 'sessionTimeout' to a value > 30 in Tomcat's default web.xml: tomcat_home/conf/web.xml or in your own web.xml and see what happens.

Comment: Ok. I tried setting session-timeout in tomcat_home/conf/web.xml to 525600 (equivalent to 1 year in mins) and I got an error at runtime saying, it could not get expire_at. Then I tried setting it to 518400 (360 days in mins) and it started working. I'm now all the more confused between session timeout and maxInactiveInterval.

Comment: This is the messy way that this Redis Session Manager is implemented :/ Nothing I can do about it.